# how to write csv in r where data is cleaned with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: r

R, Initial csv file is having Thai Language in some columns, so i set

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="Thai")

data <- read.csv("data.csv",encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Successfully read the data in Thai in R, after cleaning the data, for write.csv i gave

```
write.csv(data,"data.csv",FileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

But this is not writing back in Thai Language in csv, can someone help on this please, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try opening an encoding connection and using that to write your file:

```
encodeConnection <- file('data.csv', encoding = "UTF-8")
write.csv(data, file = encodeConnection)
```

Comment: There is no error message, csv is created, but those columns were not in thai, there are special characters like à¸«à¸¡à¸¸à¸™à¹€à¸§à¸µà¸¢à¸™à¹ƒà¸™à¸à¸´à¸ˆà¸à¸²à¸£, Thanks

Comment: To be more clear, i have queried the data from SQL server and save as csv-utf8 format, so csv itself having thai language, while loading in r, used the above code and done cleaning, for saving back having troubles in utf-8 format csv. Thanks